# Not getting the ouptut according to defined schema in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to pig latin and i tried this schema on my data,

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int, f2:int, B:bag{T:tuple(t1:int,t2:int)});
```

My sample data is

```
10,1,{(2,4),(5,6)}  
10,3,{(1,3),(6,9)}
```

On performing \d A the output on my terminal is :

```
(10,1,)  
(10,3,)
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample data you have is not in the correct format.Your load statement is using ','  as the field separator.However the tuples in the bag are also separated by ',' and hence the data is not loaded correctly.

One way to fix this is to choose a different delimiter for the fields.For example tab,pipe,semicolons.

Using Tabs as field separator and comma as tuple separator

```
10  1   {(2,4),(5,6)}
10  3   {(1,3),(6,9)}
```

Script for tab delimited fields with the schema

```
A = LOAD 'test8.txt' using PigStorage('\t') AS (f1:int, f2:int, B:bag{T:tuple(t1:int,t2:int)});
DUMP A;
```

Output

[image]

Alternatively, you can load the sample data without specifying the fields

```
10,1,{(2,4),(5,6)}
10,3,{(1,3),(6,9)}
```

Script for load without schema but with ',' as field separator

```
A = LOAD '/test8.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
DUMP A;
```

Output

[image]